# LayoutAnimation is not working in new version of reat-native like 0.60

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using from react-native library LayoutAnimation and in the componentWillUpdate() component used LayoutAnimation.spring(); but I couldn't catch any animation.

I thik that problem with new version of react-native 0.60

```
componentWillUpdate() {
    LayoutAnimation.spring();
}
```

Comment: You can use `LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring`

Comment: Can you give some example with code

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@thg303/reactnative-layoutanimation this is example